# ¿Formar un triangulo de números pares? C++

Tags: c++

Es decir que si yo ingreso que la cantidad de filas del triangulo sean 5 
se imprimira asi

```
2
4 6 
8 10 12
14 16 18 20
22 24 26 28 30
```

Comment: ¿y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Estuve revisando el centro de ayudas de Stack Overflow para estar seguro si la pregunta debería tener votos negativos o no y pienso que sería mejor reconsiderar los votos negativos emitidos  en esta pregunta, si tomamos en cuenta [qué tipo de preguntas se deben evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Es posible que no tengamos una solución a la mano para la pregunta planteada, bien sea, porque no dominamos el tema, o bien, porque no se nos ocurrió anteriormente. Pero, esto no quiere decir que necesariamente esté mala del todo. Después de todo, el planteamiento tiene una solución concreta.

Comment: @David  esta comunidad no tiene como objetivo planteamiento de retos para competir a ver quién sabe más. La pregunta no es adecuada puesto no se plantea la dificultad que tiene el OP solo hace una pregunta. Quizás reciba respuestas, pero el tema ds ¿estamos ayudando *nicolas*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Importante:** Lea toda esta respuesta.
>
> El código ya ha sido probado y también se encuentra documentado en los comentarios.

### Formación de triángulo con números pares

Una posible forma de lograr que el programa forme un triángulo con pares numéricos, sería realizando las siguientes acciones:

- Crear una función que no devuelva ningún valor. En su lugar, muestre en pantalla números pares cuando se le pase como argumento un número entero. Es decir `par( n )`.
- Crear las variables enteras `n` y `filas`, donde `n` es la variable que pasará como argumento de la función `par( n )` para mostrar en pantalla números pares y `filas`, el número de filas que formarán el triángulo.
- Crear dos (02) bucles.

  1. El primero será el bucle principal, que son las que formará las filas del triángulo, recorriendo desde `1` hasta `fila`.
  2. El segundo, que es la que estará anidada dentro del bucle principal, formando columnas de pares numéricos desde 1 hasta `i`, donde esta última es la variable *iteradora* del bucle principal para lograr que la proporción de filas y columnas, sean equivalentes.

Sin más preámbulos, empecemos con el código.

**Función `void par( int )`:**

```cpp
void par( int n ) {
  // Nos aseguramos que el número que pase como argumento sea «par»:
  n = 2 * n;

  // Se comprueba si el número par tiene solo una cifra:
  if ( n < 10 ) {

    // Si entra aquí el número es de un dígito,
    //   para que el número siempre tenga al menos dos
    //   dígitos y que queden alineados verticalmente, 
    //   mostramos un espacio a la izquierda, 
    cout << " " ;
  }

  // Ahora que ya tabulamos, mostramos el número,
  //   y agregamos otro espacio a la derecha para
  //   que sepamos dónde termina el número
  //    y dónde comienza el otro.
  cout << n << " ";
}
```

**Variables y bucles dentro la función `main()`:**

```cpp
int main() {
  // Declaramos las variables «n» y «filas»:
  int n = 0, filas = 0;

  // Le solicitamos al usuario que ingrese una cantidad
  // de filas para formar un triángulo:
  cout << "¿Cuántas filas deseas agregar al triángulo? => ";
  cin >> filas;

  // En este bucle, crearemos las filas del triángulo:
  for( int i = 1; i <= filas; i++ ) {

    // En este bucle creamos las columnas del triángulo.
    // Para conseguirlo se empieza desde 1 hasta «i», 
    // siendo la última la variable iteradora
    // del bucle principal:
    for( int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
      par( n );
      n++;
    }

    // El salto de línea por cada fila
    // que se haya formado:
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Es posible que esta no sea la mejor solución para la formación del triángulo de pares numéricos, pero se aproxima bastante. Por lo tanto, dejo todo el código completo con el menor comentario posible en ella.

**Ejemplo completo:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Prototipo de función:
void par( int );

void par( int n ) {
  n = 2 * n;

  if ( n < 10 ) {
    cout << " ";
  }
  cout << n << " ";
}

int main() {
  int n = 0, filas = 0;

  cout << "¿Cuántas filas deseas agregar al triángulo? => ";
  cin >> filas;

  for( int i = 1; i <= filas; i++ ) {

    for( int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
      par( n );
      n++;
    }

    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Que al ejecutarlo desde una terminal, asumiendo que el ejecutable que hemos generado después de la compilación del código sea **triangulo:**

```sh
usuario@linux$ ./triangulo
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

```sh
¿Cuántas filas deseas agregar al triángulo? => 10
 0 
 2  4 
 6  8 10 
12 14 16 18 
20 22 24 26 28 
30 32 34 36 38 40 
42 44 46 48 50 52 54 
56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 
72 74 76 78 80 82 84 86 88 
90 92 94 96 98 100 102 104 106 108
```

He dejado una versión del código en [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@DavidEE1/Triangulo-de-numeros-pares-3) para que lo puedan ejecutar y posteriormente probar sus resultados.

> **Importante:** El cero es un número par, por eso se incluye en el triángulo formado por números pares.

Pueden leer el siguiente fragmento tomado de la **Wikipedia**:

> En el conjunto de los enteros (ℤ), el 0 es un número par; satisface la definición de paridad, así como también todas las características de los números pares.

O [ir directamente a la fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cero#Paridad).

Comment: El cero a la izquierda es cuestionable, incluso en algunos lenguajes como _JavaScript_ poner un cero a la izquierda en un octal puede cambiar el resultado.

Comment: Es cierto @ArtEze. Lo había puesto así para mantener la consistencia en el triángulo. Sin embargo, la puedes editar reemplazando el cero (0) por un espacio en blanco de la forma " ". Puedes realizar las pruebas en [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@DavidEE1/Triangulo-de-numeros-pares-3) antes de la edición.

Comment: Incluso, si encuentras opciones mejores siempre serán bienvenidas.

Comment: Mi navegador tiene un problema con _Repl.it_, a pesar de esto, puedo hacer pruebas en _CodeBlocks_, aunque me tarda un poco en cargar. Probaré los códigos y luego comentaré.

Comment: Dale, estaré pendiente de ello.

Comment: Ya probé en _CodeBlocks_ y además hice la edición. Pensé que era mejor poner la función `par` arriba del `main`. Le hice una optimización a esa función y así evitar poner el `else`, y pude cambiar el cero por un espacio.

Comment: Probé el código, quedó bien. Gracias por la edición.

Comment: En cuanto tenga oportunidad, voy a actualizar el código en [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@DavidEE1/Triangulo-de-numeros-pares-3).

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
    int num=5;
    int a = 2;

    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        for (int b=0; b!=i; b++){
            printf("%d ", a);
            a=a+2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor considera explicar tu codigo pues responder de este modo se considera de baja calidad, más allá de que la pregunta al estar mal planteada termine cerrada